# List values by key in deserialized json object

Tags: c#, json, object

So I define

```
public class Globals
{
    public List<object> var { get; set; }
}
```

My json I'm sending is like so

`{"var":[{"test1":"1","test2","2","test3","3"}],"morejson":"blahblahblah}`

so lets say I have this now and we pretend AppendTextBox is writing a textbox in a separate thread

```
void getmedata()
{
    var commands = JsonParser.Deserialize<Globals>(json);

    AppendTextBox(commands.description[0].ToString()); 
    AppendTextBox(commands.description.Count.ToString());
}
```

`AppendTextBox(commands.description.Count.ToString());` works and shows the count

however I cannot seem to get it to print values preferably by key.  the way it is set up currently gives the following as output

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]`
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you have a strongly typed object instead of a collection of `object` items?

Comment: good question.  This is because the json comes from another machine, it has potential to be 1,2 or 3 items.

Comment: It looks like you might be able to get what you want if you change the format to: {"var":[{"test1":"1"},{"test2","2"},{"test3","3"}],"morejson":"blahblahblah}

Then bring it in as an array of objects and do a ToDictionary from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `List` of `Dictionary` use instead of `object` to access it using :

```
public class Globals
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> var { get; set; }
}
```

Then, your JSON

```
{"var":[{"test1":"1","test2","2","test3","3"}, {"anykey1": "anyvalue1", "anykey2": "anyvalue2"}, {}, {"1": "2"}], "morejson": "blahblahblah"}
```

will convert to a `List` of length 4. Each key will represent a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

For example, if you do this:

```
foreach (var keyValuePair in commands[1])
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
}
```

you will get

```
anykey1 => anyvalue1
anykey2 => anyvalue2
```